# Remove specific category from a post

Tags: categories

I have enabled categories on attachments, and I am trying to implement the logic to automatically handle the "Uncategorized" category, like this:

1) If the attachment has no categories, set it to "Uncategorized"

2) If the attachment has some category besides "Uncategorized", remove "Uncategorized" from the post's category list

I have tackled most of the logic, except that now I dont know how to remove the category from the Attachment. This is my code:

```
<?php

// Enable categories with attachments
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );

if( is_admin() ) {

    add_action('add_attachment', 'emt_set_attachment_category');
    add_action('edit_attachment', 'emt_set_attachment_category');
    function emt_set_attachment_category( $post_ID ) {

        $attachmentCategories =  wp_get_object_terms( $post_ID, 'category' );

        // if attachment has many categories, remove the default category
        if (count($attachmentCategories) > 1) {
            foreach ($attachmentCategories as $key => $category)
                if ($category->name == "Uncategorized")
                    // How to delete it??

            return;
        }

        // if attachment already have categories, stop here
        if (count($attachmentCategories) == 1)
            return;

        // if attachment has no categories, set default category
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, array( get_option('default_category') ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`wp_remove_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remove_object_terms).

```
if ($category->name == "Uncategorized") {
    wp_remove_object_terms( $post_ID, 'uncategorized', 'category' );
}
```

Untested but "Attachments" are pretty much just posts under the hood, so I am fairly sure that should work.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks! Follow-up question: Do you think I should run the "remove" inside a loop?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why would you need a loop? You are only removing a single category.

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean that I don't need the loop that I posted in the question? If I try to remove the category "uncategorized", but the attachment isnt set to that category, no error will be given?

Comment: You will need the loop you already have.

Comment: It seems like I don't! this works quite well :) https://gist.github.com/enriquemorenotent/9164197

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. But that code runs whether or not "Uncategorized" is set. I don't know if that is more or less efficient than using the Loop.

Comment: Fair point. I will worry about performance later though. Thanks :)